# Eclipse rcp application - Delete project resource programatically

Tags: eclipse, resources, project, rcp

We can delete org.eclipse.core.resources.project by belowing code in RCP Application

```
org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject::delete
```

But in my situation,

I have two applications, one is GUI RCP application, another is non-GUI RCP application. I wanna delete non-GUI application and synchronize with GUI application.

project.delete(true, null) - do nothing.

project.delete(true, true, null) - project directory has been deleted but still remains(it exists when open GUI application still).

project.open(null) > project.delete(true, null) - project directory has been deleted but still remains(it exists when open GUI application still).

How can I clean a project resources in file system and in eclipse workspace?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is resolved through the following code.

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().save(true, null);
```